# How do I create multiple post types in same menu section in WP-admin?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, admin-menu

I am building a custom menu section (a new item with subitems in the main menu section on the left side) in the WordPress Administration of my website. The section shall include a main post type, and for this you should be able to link category and country.

It would be possible to use taxonomies, but taxonomy only supports multiple choices. Therefore, I want to be able to create new post types for category and country instead of taxonomies.

But it won't work out if I want it to be under the same menu section? Please help.

Comment: It probably helps if you write what a menu section actually is. Is it a main entry in the admin menu that is displayed on the left side in the admin? Then it's probably more clear what does not work. Please edit your question accordingly, because with the current description I do not know if I really understand your problem.

Comment: Okey. I have done that now. Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

WordPress let's you define where a post type appears in the args where you register it.  It's the `show_in_menu` argument.  You can set it to true, false or a the slug (a string) of the page under which you'd like it to appear.

So, let's say you already have a post type "main".  To display another post type under that you'd set the `show_in_menu` argument, like so:

```
<?php

// the register the post type
add_action( 'init', 'wpse4178_register' );
function wpse4178_register()
{
    // probably some more args up here.
    $args['show_in_menu'] = 'edit.php?post_type=main';
    register_post_type( 'country', $args );
}
```

Comment: Your $args array must be inside of your function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the menu individually by code, most certainly by a plugin. [Administration Menus (Wordpress Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus) contains a lot of information how the menu can be controlled. If nothing helps, you can [directly control the menu via the associated global variable](http://hungred.com/how-to/remove-wordpress-admin-menu-affecting-wordpress-core-system/).